# Using getOption in parallel execution

Tags: r

I have problem understanding why using `getOption` to retrieve option which I've manually set returns `NULL` in parallel execution using `foreach` while it correctly returns other options:

```
library(foreach)

options(my_option = 1)

f <- function(option){
  
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl), add = TRUE)
  on.exit(foreach::registerDoSEQ(), add = TRUE)
  
  foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% {getOption(option)}
}
```

Examples:

```
f("warn")
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 0

f("my_option")
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

I know I could use `.export` parameter, but I would like solution without using it if such solution is possible.

Comment: I'm clearly no expert on parallel questions so maybe I'm completely wrong, but the description of `?foreach` says: "The expression [...] is evaluated multiple times in an environment that is created by the foreach object, and that environment is modified for each evaluation as specified by the foreach object". So to me it looks like `getOption(option)` returns the same thing as it would return in an empty session: `0` for "warn" and `NULL` for "my_option".

Comment: Maybe try `foreach(i = 1:3, .options.multicore = "my_option") %dopar% {getOption(option)}`

Comment: @Sotos Interesting: [this mechanism does not seem to be documented](https://rdrr.io/cran/foreach/man/foreach.html).  Do you know how to find more information about it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I found it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf) on chapter 7, but yes you are right. It's not the `foreach`, its one called `doMC` that provides that option